# How to add ref="nofollow" on blogger reply and delete comment links

Tags: javascript, blogger, blogspot

I used seo analyser tool http://www.seoptimer.com for my blog post and found that my comment delete link are "dofollow". Now, how can i add "nofollow" in those links.

I am using embedded comments by blogger.

Page url: http://www.howbloggerz.com/2016/02/custom-stylish-search-boxes-blogger.html

Comment script:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
  var items = <data:post.commentJso/>;
  var msgs = <data:post.commentMsgs/>;
  var config = <data:post.commentConfig/>;

// <![CDATA[
  var cursor = null;
  if (items && items.length > 0) {
    cursor = parseInt(items[items.length - 1].timestamp) + 1;
  }

  var bodyFromEntry = function(entry) {
    if (entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
      for (var k in entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
        if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].name == 'blogger.contentRemoved') {
          return '<span class="deleted-comment">' + entry.content.$t + '</span>';
        }
      }
    }
    return entry.content.$t;
  }

  var parse = function(data) {
    cursor = null;
    var comments = [];
    if (data && data.feed && data.feed.entry) {
      for (var i = 0, entry; entry = data.feed.entry[i]; i++) {
        var comment = {};
        // comment ID, parsed out of the original id format
        var id = /blog-(\d+).post-(\d+)/.exec(entry.id.$t);
        comment.id = id ? id[2] : null;
        comment.body = bodyFromEntry(entry);
        comment.timestamp = Date.parse(entry.published.$t) + '';
        if (entry.author && entry.author.constructor === Array) {
          var auth = entry.author[0];
          if (auth) {
            comment.author = {
              name: (auth.name ? auth.name.$t : undefined),
              profileUrl: (auth.uri ? auth.uri.$t : undefined),
              avatarUrl: (auth.gd$image ? auth.gd$image.src : undefined)
            };
          }
        }
        if (entry.link) {
          if (entry.link[2]) {
            comment.link = comment.permalink = entry.link[2].href;
          }
          if (entry.link[3]) {
            var pid = /.*comments\/default\/(\d+)\?.*/.exec(entry.link[3].href);
            if (pid && pid[1]) {
              comment.parentId = pid[1];
            }
          }
        }
        comment.deleteclass = 'item-control blog-admin';
        if (entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
          for (var k in entry.gd$extendedProperty) {
            if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].name == 'blogger.itemClass') {
              comment.deleteclass += ' ' + entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].value;
            } else if (entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].name == 'blogger.displayTime') {
              comment.displayTime = entry.gd$extendedProperty[k].value;
            }
          }
        }
        comments.push(comment);
      }
    }
    return comments;
  };

  var paginator = function(callback) {
    if (hasMore()) {
      var url = config.feed + '?alt=json&v=2&orderby=published&reverse=false&max-results=200';
      if (cursor) {
        url += '&published-min=' + new Date(cursor).toISOString();
      }
      window.bloggercomments = function(data) {
        var parsed = parse(data);
        cursor = parsed.length < 50 ? null
            : parseInt(parsed[parsed.length - 1].timestamp) + 1
        callback(parsed);
        window.bloggercomments = null;
      }
      url += '&callback=bloggercomments';
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = url;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }
  };
  var hasMore = function() {
    return !!cursor;
  };
  var getMeta = function(key, comment) {
    if ('iswriter' == key) {
      var matches = !!comment.author
          && comment.author.name == config.authorName
          && comment.author.profileUrl == config.authorUrl;
      return matches ? 'true' : '';
    } else if ('deletelink' == key) {
      return config.baseUri + '/delete-comment.g?blogID='
           + config.blogId + '&postID=' + comment.id;
    } else if ('deleteclass' == key) {
      return comment.deleteclass;
    }
    return '';
  };

  var replybox = null;
  var replyUrlParts = null;
  var replyParent = undefined;

  var onReply = function(commentId, domId) {
    if (replybox == null) {
      // lazily cache replybox, and adjust to suit this style:
      replybox = document.getElementById('comment-editor');
      if (replybox != null) {
        replybox.height = '250px';
        replybox.style.display = 'unset';
        replyUrlParts = replybox.src.split('#');
      }
    }
    if (replybox && (commentId !== replyParent)) {
      document.getElementById(domId).insertBefore (document.getElementById ('threaded-comment-form'), null);
      replybox.src = replyUrlParts[0]
          + (commentId ? '&parentID=' + commentId : '')
          + '#' + replyUrlParts[1];
      replyParent = commentId;
    }
  };

  var hash = (window.location.hash || '#').substring(1);
  var startThread, targetComment;
  if (/^comment-form_/.test(hash)) {
    startThread = hash.substring('comment-form_'.length);
  } else if (/^c[0-9]+$/.test(hash)) {
    targetComment = hash.substring(1);
  }

  // Configure commenting API:
  var configJso = {
    'maxDepth': config.maxThreadDepth
  };
  var provider = {
    'id': config.postId,
    'data': items,
    'loadNext': paginator,
    'hasMore': hasMore,
    'getMeta': getMeta,
    'onReply': onReply,
    'rendered': true,
    'initComment': targetComment,
    'initReplyThread': startThread,
    'config': configJso,
    'messages': msgs
  };

  var render = function() {
    if (window.goog && window.goog.comments) {
      var holder = document.getElementById('comment-holder');
      window.goog.comments.render(holder, provider);
    }
  };

  // render now, or queue to render when library loads:
  if (window.goog && window.goog.comments) {
    render();
  } else {
    window.goog = window.goog || {};
    window.goog.comments = window.goog.comments || {};
    window.goog.comments.loadQueue = window.goog.comments.loadQueue || [];
    window.goog.comments.loadQueue.push(render);
  }
})();
```

// ]]>

Comment: Please show your representative HTML (of, presumably, the comments) and explain where you got stuck. See the "*[MCVE]*" guidelines, for what we need in your question in order to answer it usefully. Links to external resources, particularly to your own live site, are prone to link-rot and, once your problem is solved, the code will be corrected; this means that the question will have no further use in the future when others are searching for answers to their own (similar) issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `rel="nofollow"` attribute to the `<a>` tag.

It is as simple as this

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="link here">My Link</a>
```

**Specifically for blogger**

- Go to template>Edit HTML>Proceed.
- Click tick on Expand Widget Template.
- Now search for this code by pressing Ctrl+f.

  expr:href=’data:post.createlinkurl’

Now add `rel=”external nofollow”` just after the above code like this.

```
expr:href='data:post.createlinkurl' rel="external nofollow"
```

After this `nofollow` attribute will appear in the comments in your blog.

**Add all External link with nofollow**

- Go to your Blogger Dashboard >> Template.
- Click on the Edit HTML button.
- Find the  tag by pressing ctrl+f  and typing  in the
  search box.

Now add the following code above the  tag :

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var a = $(this);
    var href = a.attr('href');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[href^='http://']").each(function() {
            if (this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
                $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
                $(this).attr('title', 'Click to open in a new window');
                $(this).attr('rel', 'nofollow');
            }
        });
        $("a[href^='https://']").each(function() {
            if (this.href.indexOf(location.hostname) == -1) {
                $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
                $(this).attr('title', 'Click to open in a new window');
                $(this).attr('rel', 'nofollow');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But i was not successful in finding that link in my template because the comments are using java-script to make their structure. You can see script in page url src.

Comment: Updated answer based on your comment

Comment: i applied your suggestions but no success. :(

Comment: Can you please check now?

Comment: I appreciate your help. Is there any way to add nofollow only on Reply and delete links under each comment. Thanks for doing this much for me :)

Comment: I will suggest you to search if some plugin provides that. Also If possible switch to wordpress much better and more customizable than blogspot.